# Cant send NULL to a function getting vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have this function:

```
    void RegMatrix::MatrixInit(int numRow,int numCol, std::vector<double> fill)

    {

      do something;

    }
```

and i want to send this:

```
MatrixInit(numRow,numCol,NULL);
```

how can i pass NULL as vector?

Comment: NULL is not a vector. What would you like it to mean when you pass NULL for that parameter?

Comment: i come from java, its a hard world here at c++, iwant an empty vector

Comment: Then you should also appreciate that a null pointer is not an empty vector in Java, either.

Comment: in java you can send null instaed of empty vector

Comment: In java you're actually sending a vector pointer as well.  Remy Lebeau - TeamB's answer is most java-like, but K-ballo's answer is more C++ -like

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot pass NULL as vector, you could instead pass an empty vector like this:

```
MatrixInit( numRow, numCol, std::vector<double>() )
```

Note that you would be better off taking the `fill` vector as `const&`.

Comment: Presumably the function is supposed to change the vector.

Comment: Oh is it? There is no reference for that and I assumed fill were the initial values for the matrix. If that's the case, then it should be & rather than const&, of course.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, since the original was pass-by-value it *couldn't* change the vector.

Comment: @Mark I said _presumably_, drawing from the name of the function. The signature of the function implies the function has zero side-effects, not even a return-value, and I _guess_ that's a mistake.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: It's a non const member function, pressumably to initialize the object.

Comment: holy lazer beams of batman, it's true. i was skimming so fast didn't even realize it's a member. :-S

Answer (score 13):

In order to pass `NULL`, you need to change your parameter to accept a `vector*` pointer instead, eg:

```
void RegMatrix::MatrixInit(int numRow, int numCol, std::vector<double> *fill)
{
    if (fill != NULL)
    {
        do something with fill;
    }
}
```

When you need to pass in a vector, you would then do it like this:

```
std::vector<double> v;
MatrixInit(numRow, numCol, &v);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a value that represents a special case, you can make a static variable and test against it.

```
static std::vector<double> null_fill;

void RegMatrix::MatrixInit(int numRow,int numCol, const std::vector<double> & fill = null_fill)
{
    if (&fill == &null_fill)
        // do something special
    else
        // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the argument type `boost::optional<std::vector<double> >`

As the name says, that's an optional argument. If you don't use the argument, you pass `boost::none` instead. (not `NULL`; that's a null pointer constant and we're not using pointers here).

Answer (score 0):

You `cannot` have a `null` vector in C++.

C++ is a `value-type` language.A variable of type vector contains the value of vector directly, `NOT` a reference to a vector like in `java`.

```
MatrixInit(numRow,numCol,NULL);
```

The above statement will give you an error : Cannot convert `NULL`(zero) to `std::vector`.